# How to get fingerprinted css url on client side in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I need to dynamically add stylesheet in rails app from client side. How can I get the fingerprinted url on client side. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: where does that `css` file present?

Comment: Are they choosing personal style themes or something?  You need to save it to the database if you want it persist or else you'll need them to choose their styles everytime they clear their browser history...

Comment: @Sravan Inside assets/stylesheets